# How do I extract values under <li> that are under <ul class =...> using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, append

*Preface:* I am doing web-scraping on a real estate website out of curiosity.
Being a complete newbie for python, I have been modifying codes from other shared codes as a way to learn.
I stumbled upon a new challenge that I have never learned how to do this anywhere. So, I would like to ask the community for help.

*What I want:* I would like to extract the values "4" and "3" under the `<li>` elements as separate items. Please see the image I attached to this post for the excerpt of elements from the website.

*What I attempted:* I see that they are listed under div class="list-card-heading" so I tried `card.find("div", {"class":"list-card-heading"}).find("ul").find("li"))` in the code below for the attribute named 'bed_bath'. But I only got the first value embeded in the HTML...

```
content = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
        deck = content.find('ul',{'class':'photo-cards photo-cards_wow photo-cards_short'})
        for card in deck.contents:
            script = card.find('script',{'type': 'application/ld+json'})
            if script:
                script_json = json.loads(script.contents[0])

                self.results.append({
                    'latitude': script_json['geo']['latitude'],
                    'longitude': script_json['geo']['longitude'],
                    'floorSize': script_json['floorSize']['value'],
                    'url': script_json['url'],
                    'price': card.find('div', {'class': 'list-card-price'}).text,
                    'bed_bath': (card.find("div", {"class":"list-card-heading"}).find("ul").find("li")),
                    'address': card.find('address', {'class':'list-card-addr'}).text
                })
```

*Result from my newbie attempt:* `<li>3<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->bds</abbr></li>`

Please help

Image:
[Elements from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN6C2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a combination of the `find_all` function and the `text` attribute.

```py
elements = card.find("div", { "class": "list-card-heading" }).find("ul").find_all("li")) # get all <li> elements in the <el>

values = []
for element in elements:
    values.append(element.text) # get the inner text from the <li> element
```

or, more concisely:

```py
values = [element.text for element in card.find("div", { "class": "list-card-heading" }).find("ul").find_all("li"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `["3", "4"]` from the HTML snippet, you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<ul class="list-card-details">
<li>
    "4"
    <abbr class="list-card-label">bds</abbr>
</li>
<li>
    "3"
    <abbr class="list-card-label">ba</abbr>
</li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = [li.contents[0].strip() for li in soup.select('ul.list-card-details li')]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['"4"', '"3"']
```

---

Or:

```
out = [li.find(text=True).strip() for li in soup.select('ul.list-card-details li')]
```

---

Or:

```
out = [li.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[0] for li in soup.select('ul.list-card-details li')]
```